# Shell in Unix: db2 database with data with umlaut not exported to CSV

Tags: shell, db2

I have written a .sh file and in this .sh file I have selected some data which exports a .csv file.
I recognized that all the lines with umlaut (ä,ö,ü etc.) are not considered to be exported, and the rest of the data are okay. So I think it might be a problem of data format in shell code.
I used "UTF-8" to encode the .sh file.
And my db2 code is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE something IN ('aktiviert', 'gekündigt','beendet')
```

I suppose there is something wrong with "gekündigt". Could someone help?
Many thanks!

Comment: In your *shell* session that runs the script, you need to set the value of the LANG variable to the correct locale to match your data (and that locale has to be installed in your operating system). Have you done that?  For example `export LANG=de_DE.utf8` if your territory is German, and that locale is installed, and if your shell is bash or similar.

Answer (score 1):

In your shell session that runs the script, you need to set the value of the LANG variable to the correct locale to match your data (and that locale has to be installed in your operating system).

You can set this variable before you run the `db2 export` command. You can set the variable in your shell startup profile, or in your `userprofile` (of the Db2-instance, if you have one), or in your script as long as you make the variable exportable to subshells.

Usually it is convenient  to have a system default locale and to arrange that every shell login session has the correct LANG setting automatic.

For example `export LANG=de_DE.utf8` if your territory is German, and that locale is installed, and if your shell is bash or similar. If your territory is Switzerland or Austria, or other territory, look in your `locale` output to find the best match.

If your client operating system is MS-Windows, different configuration applies, as per the regional settings of MS-Windows, although in some cases setting DB2CODEPAGE=1208 environment variable for UTF-8 can help.

Keep in mind that the EXPORT command for `db2` command line also supports syntax `modified by codepage=x` *where x is a codepage number* which can also help. Refer to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html). The aim is that either zero codepage conversion happens during the export (it can lead to data issues in the exported contents and possible loss of data), or that the codepage conversion finds correct matching / equivalent characters between the database-codepage and the client (i.e. your `db2` CLP in your shell script) side application-codepage.